# How to use comparatives with processive nouns?

Tags: grammaticality, possessives, comparatives

I wonder which of the following is/are correct?

a. The national flag of Malaysia has more colours than Japan's.
b. The national flag of Malaysia has more colours than Japan.
c. Malaysia's national flag has more colours than Japan's.

Comment: Welcome, Esther. What makes you believe any of them might be better or worse? What have you done already to find your answer?

Comment: Plus, I think that in your title you mean *possessive*? I’d suggest you edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Version c. is perfectly idiomatic.

Version a. mixes **of Malaysia** and **Japan's**, and while it is grammatical, and idiomatic, one might wonder, why the mixing?

Version b. compares a flag to a country, which is very clumsy, yet many native speakers would say it, and people would know exactly what they meant by it, so we shouldn't consider it ungrammatical. But most editors would "fix" it.